# IfeatureLayer.search() second time return error

Tags: arcobjects, c#, cursor, feature-layer, search

I have the following method in my code and have a button that when clicked run this code. In the first click all of code runs without error. but in second run I receive an error on line:
`IFeatureCursor fcDistrict = flDistrict.Search(null, false);`

Error:`Exception from HRESULT: 0x8005018B`

```
Void function(){ 
    IFeatureLayer flCircuit = ClsGeneral.FindLayer(ClsShares.FC_CIRCUIT);
    IFeatureLayer flSubstat = ClsGeneral.FindLayer(ClsShares.FC_SUBSTAT);
    IFeatureLayer flLoad_center = ClsGeneral.FindLayer(ClsShares.FC_LOAD_CENTER);
    IFeatureLayer flDistrict = ClsGeneral.FindLayer(ClsShares.FC_DISTRICT);

    IFeatureCursor fcDistrict = flDistrict.Search(null, false);

    IFeature fDistrict = fcDistrict.NextFeature();
    ISpatialFilter sf = new SpatialFilterClass();
    while (fDistrict != null)
    {
        int indCFCapacity = fDistrict.Fields.FindField("HIGHDIST_CIRCUIT_FREE_CAPACITY");
        int indHSFCapacity = fDistrict.Fields.FindField("HIGHDIST_SUBSTAT_FREE_CAPACITY");
        int indTSFCapacity = fDistrict.Fields.FindField("TRANSFER_SUBSTAT_FREE_CAPACITY");
        fDistrict.set_Value(indCFCapacity, 0);
        fDistrict.set_Value(indHSFCapacity, 0);
        fDistrict.set_Value(indTSFCapacity, 0);

        sf.SpatialRel = esriSpatialRelEnum.esriSpatialRelIntersects;
        sf.Geometry = fDistrict.Shape;
        sf.GeometryField = flDistrict.FeatureClass.ShapeFieldName;
        IFeatureCursor fcCircuit = flCircuit.Search(sf, true);
        IFeature fCircuit = fcCircuit.NextFeature();
        while (fCircuit != null)
        {
            int indVol = fCircuit.Fields.FindField("UTNOM_VOLT");
            int indFCCapacity = fCircuit.Fields.FindField("FREE_CAPACITY");
            int Vol;
            int.TryParse(fCircuit.get_Value(indVol).ToString(), out Vol);
            if (Vol < 132)
            {
                double oldValue;
                double.TryParse(fDistrict.get_Value(indCFCapacity).ToString(), out oldValue);
                double sumValue;
                double.TryParse(fCircuit.get_Value(indFCCapacity).ToString(), out sumValue);
                fDistrict.set_Value(indCFCapacity, oldValue + sumValue);
            }
            fCircuit = fcCircuit.NextFeature();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Release your cursors  (e.g. fcDistrict) when you are finished with it. you are opening two update cursor on a single feature class.

put these lines at the end of your function:

```
if (fcDistrict!=null)
ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.ComReleaser.ReleaseCOMObject(fcDistrict);

fcDistrict= null;
```

For further information see this post:

[ArcObjects .NET - How to close/release FeatureClass, Workspace, Factory](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118409/arcobjects-net-how-to-close-release-featureclass-workspace-factory?lq=1)

Comment: No. Problem is not from that, I tested that and didn't work. But this code is in method, and originally when method ended that's component released